# How to give field level access right to a particular group in odoo?

Tags: security, odoo, odoo-10, usergroups

A form contains over 5 fields. A certain group user is given read access alone in the csv security. But I want that particular group user to access two fields in that form view. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the attribute `groups='module_that_defines_the_group.group_name'` to your field, something like this `<field name="currency_id" groups="base.group_multi_currency"/>`. I Hope this can be helpfull for you.

Comment: If i do like this, that field will be visible to that particular group only. But my requirement is not that. I want that particular group to edit that field alone. My question is How to give write access to that group user for a particular field? @Juan Salcedo